# Get Value of Property (List<long>) in Post Action in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

This is My model:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public List<long> NeededIds { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

My Controllers:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    MyModel model = new MyModel();
    model.NeededIds = new List<long> { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(MyModel model)
{
    string name = model.Name;
    List<long> ids = model.NeededIds;
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

And View:

```
@model TestMVC.Models.MyModel

@using(Html.BeginForm()) {

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Id
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach(long id in Model.NeededIds) { 
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @id
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>MyModel</legend>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}
```

I set `NeededIds` in Get action and in the view I can see `NeededIds`. I also need it in Post action, but in post action the `NeededIds` is always null. How can I get the property value in post action when I set it in get action? What is your suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not posting your `NeededIds` back to the server. In order to get this working you can add them as hidden fields in a for loop inside the form:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.NeededIds.Count(); i++) { 
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.NeededIds[i])
}
```

Comment: That's weird, why I set them again when I set them before?

Comment: That's the way HTTP works - it is stateless. Whatever you set before in your model does not get persisted on the server between requests. Thus you need to post the `NeededIds` back along with the rest of your model, otherwise they get lost.

Answer (score 1):

if you are  using layout page than simply remove the form tag from the layout page.

Answer (score 0):

in addition to the answer by Yakimych
you have kept the ids as constant.. this means two things
1. you can use arrays in place of list
2.you can just save the ids list/array in `TempData` and retrive it back from there when POST happens
you can do this like this
in your GET handler

```
TempData.Add("ids",idArray);
```

in your POST handler

```
var idArray = (long[])TempData["ids"];
```

Comment: This is actually a case where one should NOT use `TempData`. See http://rachelappel.com/when-to-use-viewbag-viewdata-or-tempdata-in-asp.net-mvc-3-applications, specifically this part: `Since TempData works this way, you need to know for sure what the next request will be, and redirecting to another view is the only time you can guarantee this`. Since you are not doing `RedirectToAction` or something similar here, you cannot guarantee what the next request will be and the `Ids` can indeed get lost.

Comment: i think here also the first request is GET and the very next request in the same session will be post.. so saving in TempData wont be a problem

Comment: I can't stress this enough - you can NOT guarantee it. And it's pretty easy to break anyway. Do a simple test if you want to make sure. Open the page in one browser tab, do a bunch of requests to other actions in another browser tab, and then do your POST request in the first one. Your `TempData` will be lost.